# Lógica para inibir registro permanentemente

Tags: xml, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Galera tenho um "problemão" e não consigo pensar em nada para resolve-lo por isso gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Tenho um sistema desktop que é o intermediário entre o servidor e meu sistema web. Esse sistema desktop faz duas consultas no banco de dados a cada uma hora e grava esses dados em um arquivo `.xml`

No sistema Web eu leio esses arquivos e carrego os dados em tabelas. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver tem um `commandButton` em cada linha, esse botão abre um `Dialog` e carrega outros dados do segundo `.xml`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O **problema** é o seguinte. Toda vez que eu clicar em `enviar auditoria` ou `concluir auditoria` o Cliente tem que parar de aparecer na primeira tela. Porem como vou fazer isso se o `xml` é atualizado a cada 1 hora, se eu editar o pro cliente não aparecer mais daqui 1 hora o `xml` será atualizado e ele irá aparecer.

Alguém pode ajudar?

---

Código:
Eu pego os dados do `xml` no `Get` da `List`

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dtBasicView")
@ViewScoped
public class SolicitacoesBean {
    private List<Solicitacoes> list;
    private List<Solicitacoes> listaFiltrada;
    private Solicitacoes solicitacoes;



    public List<Solicitacoes> getList() {
        // pega a lista com os dados do .xml
        try {
            list = XmlParserSolicitacoes
                    .realizaLeituraXML("C:\\Solicitacoes.xml");

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Minha `DataTable`:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado" var="lista"
                value="#{dtBasicView.list}"
                filteredValue="#{dtBasicView.listaFiltrada}" rows="10"
                paginator="true" style="margin-top: 5px;"
                rowKey="#{lista.codigoBeneficiario}">

                <p:column headerText="Código" filterBy="#{lista.codigoBeneficiario}" style="width:20%" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.codigoBeneficiario}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nome" filterBy="#{lista.nomePessoa}" style="width:45%;"
                    sortBy="#{lista.nomePessoa}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.nomePessoa}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Senha" style="width:10%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.senha}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Data Solic." style="width:20%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.dataSolicitacao}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Status" style="width:22%" sortBy="#{lista.status}" filterBy="#{lista.status}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{lista.status}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Opções" style="width:7%">
                    <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-search"
                        action="#{dtBasicView.abrirDialogo}" process="@this">
                        <!--                Mandar informação para outra página -->
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dtBasicView.solicitacoes}" value="#{lista}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver gravando esses dados também em uma base de dados você pode fazer a verificação por nome.

Você tem uma rotina que lê o XML e extrai os dados na tela, correto ?

Cria uma tabela numa base de dados, tipo, *clientes_auditoria*. Cada vez que clicar em **Enviar Auditoria** você grava um registro com o nome do cliente.

E na rotina que lê o XML você verifica:

*pseudo-code*

```
Select * From Cliente_Auditoria Where Nome = Campo_Nome_XML
Count(Select)

    If Count == 0
        Mostra
    End If
```

Mostra apenas os que não tem na tabela ainda.

Comment: Mas esse é o problema os dados da tabela vem direto do xml, como eu posso parar de exibi-los? Eu posso gravar no banco e fazer a verificação o que eu não entendo mesmo é como não mostra-los.

Comment: Não mostrá-los você controla na rotina. Você tem uma base de dados ? Veja meu código.

Comment: Sim eu vi, e até entendi. Deixa eu tentar dar uma resumida. A primeira tabela é preenchida por dados que são lidos de um arquivo xml. Esse arquivo xml é gerado por outro sistema a cada 1 hora. Ou seja, o arquivo ira ser atualizado(Sobrescrito) a cada uma hora.

Comment: Tem como não mostrar os dados enviados ou concluídos na tabela sem mexer no xml? Por exemplo, uma condição onde percorro minha Lista que manda os dados pra tabela e verifica e se algum item for igual a algum dado de meu banco eu não mostro na tabela?

Comment: Exato. Não é necessário mexer no XML. Apenas grave os clientes em uma tabela separada na base de dados. E na hora da listagem você faz um `select` verificando se o nome que está vindo do XML existe na tabela. Se não existir você mostra.

Comment: Entendi a lógica e vou fazer isso, só não sei ainda como vou fazer a condição, mas vou tentar e jaja posto se consegui

Comment: Posta seu código, principalmente o que você lista os dados no XML. A condição é a que eu postei no meu comentário.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Conseguiu fazer a comunicação ?

Comment: Estou tentando ainda, estou reestruturando o código e criando as entidades

Comment: Consegui salvar os dados no banco, agora como seria a Query no Hibernate?